# UIview size greate than 5462 not drawing any graphics

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am drawing line in my projects using UibezierPath, i am calculating and drawing line according to current width and another params. But, i have noticed that if view (in which i am drawing lines )'s width exceed 5462, it doesn't show up.

Is there something that i am missing, or there is limitations of maximum size of uiview or anything else.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you draw a line with 5462 in a bigger `UIView` (a subview of your main view, for example), is still the same result?

Comment: @aramusss   Actually i have added the view in scrollview and then i update content size of scrollview. And based on that content size i gave size to that view. So the scrollview is the superView of UIView

Comment: To avoid any unrelated problems, have you tried adding this big line in a simple big `UIView` being a child of the viewController's view?

Comment: I cannot do that as i have to scroll the same drawing.

Comment: @aramusss Yes, i have tried adding single big line in big UIView but it gives same result.